# Understanding the Normalization/Standardization of geospatial coordinates

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, standardization, feature-engineering, feature-scaling

I'm building a neural network to predict future `[latitude,longitude,altitude]`, and am having trouble dealing with the features. I've reviewed the answers to the questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330800/how-to-normalize-gps-coordinates-for-deep-learning) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13567/ways-to-deal-with-longitude-latitude-feature/13575#13575) and I'm still trying to understand the points made about normalizing/standardizing.

The way I understand it, converting latitude and longitude to cartesian coordinates is a way of normalizing, is this correct?  When the answer states 'standardized', does that mean throwing the data into something like a `StandardScaler()`?

Additionally, there is a comment in the post linked second that states that I don't need the radius of the earth R because it will be standardized anyway. Why is this the case? If I took the inverse transform of the standardized data and then tried to convert the values back to latitude and longitude, wouldn't I need R?

Comment: $R$ merely establishes a unit of measurement for distances.  BTW, converting to Cartesian coordinates is not ordinarily considered a form of "normalization." Whether it's appropriate depends on the spatial extent of the data, their meaning, and your conception of spatial interactions.  You don't need `R` to do any of these calculations (although it's capable of them).  Most have been done by hand for at least 2500 years.